# How to open and save excel files with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, automation

I have excel files that execute some codes when they are open. 
I have the code below to open them automatically. I would like to let it stay open for 1 minute and then save and close the file. and move on to the next file.

How do I:

1. Ask it to wait for 1 minute, and
2. Automatically save and close them?

My code to open the file:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/EXCEL.EXE', 'example_file.xlsx'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, capture_output=False, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, check=False, encoding=None, errors=None, text=None, env=None, universal_newlines=None)
```

The arguments stdout and stderr allow you to specify what should be done with the output from the run. If you assign these to a writeable open file, that file will contain the output. For example:

```
with open(‘my-stdout.txt’, ‘w’) as fp:
    subprocess.run(myargs, stdout=fp)
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. i cannot get it to run. with the excel file, I need to leave it open for 10-20 seconds so it can return the data before saving. Is there a way to do that?, also, with your code, do I replace "myargs" with ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/EXCEL.EXE', 'example_file.xlsx']?

Answer (score 0):

There are two modules for reading xls file : openpyxl and xlrd
Or if you're using Pandas there's an inbuilt module pandas.read_excel() which you can use.

Why wait for 1 minute, just open the excel file in write mode with 'w' parameter and close it after your automation code is completed.
eg:

```
import pandas as pd
fileLocation = 'Complete_address_of_your_file'
df = pd.read_excel(fileLocation)
# Your executable code!!
```

It'd be better to read more about them. Just look for their documentation or some youtube tutorial. I believe a similar solution has been posted on stackoverflow before also coz I too encountered the same error once.

Or is it that you're trying to execute some code [malicious maybe] encapsulating it as an excel file?

Comment: My excel file contains a code in the first cell (A1). That code will be executed the moment the file is open. the code looks like this "=holdings(some parameters)". This code is from the Morningstar Excel add-in that is used to download data. Once the file is open and the code is executed, Excel would run for 10-20 secs and returns data. I would then save them (ideally save as another csv file). This is a manual procedure.  I have 10,000 files like that and cannot manually open each file